# My program gives wrong answers between 3-10 C

Tags: python

I started programming 3 days ago. This shows wrong results between 3-10 C, how can I fix it?

```
x = input("what C is it today: ")
if x < str(20):
    print("Its cold")
    print("Wear a jacket")
if str(20) <= x < str(30):
    print("Its a nice day")
    print("don't forget to have fun")
if x >= str(30):
    print("Its hot")
    print("open the air conditioner")
```

Comment: Please repaste your code and format it properly. It isn't very legible as-is. Also note what you expect to happen, and what's actually happening

Comment: Instead of using `x < str(20)`, if you want to use integer comparisons, you should try `int(x) < 20`.

Comment: You use `\`\`\`` to do block code

Comment: `x = int(input("what C is it today: "))` would avoid multiple conversions.

Comment: Your problem is that `"5" > "30"` while you expect `5 < 30`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `str(20), ...` use `int(x)`.

That happens because of comparing string is a little different than strings.

try like below:

```
x = input("what C is it today: ")
x = int(x) # here we cast x to an Integer

if x < 20:
    print("Its cold", "Wear a jacket") # you can pass multiple value 
if 20 <= x < 30:
    print("Its a nice day", "don't forget to have fun")
if x >= 30:
    print("Its hot", "open the air conditioner")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mehrdad, said so, input() assumes what you typed, is a string. so you should convert the input into an int type.

And i can spot other improvements you can make to the code. For example:
Use `elif` and `else` statements for conditions that are related to each other/ in the process of elimination (like if it is not 1, it is 2)

```
x = int( input("what C is it today: ") ) # input (string to integer)


if x < 20:
    print("Its cold", "Wear a jacket") # you can pass multiple value 
elif 20 <= x < 30:
    print("Its a nice day", "don't forget to have fun")
else: # this condition is not needed, because we eliminated the possibilities that x is less than 30, so everything else that passes the two above statements are 30 or above.
    print("Its hot", "open the air conditioner")
```